# Hover over column header for description in dash datatable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm able to use tooltip_data to hover over some cells and display some data.

Is there a way of doing this for the headers? So I can add a brief description of what each column represents?

I had a look here but it doesn't really answer whether it's possible or not. https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-datatable-tooltips/6327/3

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using dash bootstrap components [tooltips](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/tooltip/).

The syntax for the tooltip component looks like this:

```
dbc.Tooltip(
    "Noun: rare, "
    "the action or habit of estimating something as worthless.",
    target="tooltip-target",
),
```

To get this tooltip to pop up over the header of a specific column, you need it's class id and the table id (otherwise the tooltip will potentially appear over every table in your app). The class id can be found using your browsers developer tools to inspect the dashboard elements. So for the 2nd column in a table with an id of "test-table" the tooltip component should look like this:

```
dbc.Tooltip(
    "Test tooltip",
    target="test-table th.dash-header.column-1",
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky. This was a highly requested feature and has been recently implemented.

```
records = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df,
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],

    tooltip_header={
        'col_1': 'Column 1',
        'col_2': 'Column 2',
    },

    # Overflow into ellipsis
    style_cell={
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
        'maxWidth': 0,
    },
    tooltip_delay=0,
    tooltip_duration=None
)
```